How can I pass a variable from CSV file to Oracle SQL query fetch in Python?
I have the following piece of code where I read a csv file and connect to the database. then I want to pass two columns from CSV file as variable to my query and eventually convert the result to a pd database.
I have tried different ways of binding and converted columns to list but I was unsuccessful. with this piece of code I get the following
Error:
DatabaseError: DPY-4010: a bind variable replacement value  
for placeholder ":HOUR" was not provided

or I get below error when I add this part to execute():
res = connection.cursor().execute("SELECT HOUR,UNITSCHEDULEID,VERSIONID,MINRUNTIME FROM 
 int_Stg.UnitScheduleOfferHourly WHERE  Hour in :1 AND UnitScheduleId in :2", hour, unitid)

TypeError: Cursor.execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

the following is the code I execute:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"csv.csv") 

df=df.dropna()

unitid=df['UNITSCHEDULEID'].unique()
hour=df['GMT_DATETIME'].unique()

import os, oracledb, csv, pyodbc
TNS_Admin = os.environ.get('TNS_Admin', r'\\corp.xxx\oracle')
oracledb.defaults.config_dir = TNS_Admin
pw = input(f'Enter password: ')
connection = oracledb.connect(user='xxxxx', password= pw, dsn="World")

res = connection.cursor().execute("SELECT HOUR,UNITSCHEDULEID,VERSIONID,MINRUNTIME FROM 
 int_Stg.UnitScheduleOfferHourly WHERE  Hour in :Hour AND UnitScheduleId in :unitid").fetchall()
print(res)

connection.close()



usually execute(query, data). In query you have :Hour and :unitid so  you need two values in data, and it may need to use correct values

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

if you tried some binding then show it in question (not in comment) - it helps us to see what can makes problem. We can't run your code, we can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question (not in comments)

BTW: in query you have :Hour but error shows :HOUR - maybe you used wrong name.

The data part of the execute needs to be a tuple like execute("query", (param1, param2, ))

@furas   I am aware of all above, non helps. Thank you

@OneCricketeer , I will convert, any other thing wrong with the code in your mind?

You might get an error that a pandas series cannot be bound to the query and it might have to be a native Python list

I have tried Tolist() but same error,

with this code I get the following error:
print(res)```

DatabaseError: DPY-4010: a bind variable replacement value for placeholder ":HOURX" was not provided

you have query with :hourx and :unitidx" but you didn't send valued to this query - you have execute(query) but you need execute(query, values)

As the Python OracleDB documentation for Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause states, you need to generate a statement with a bind variable for every value in the arrays and then pass in those values to the bind variables:
query = """SELECT HOUR, UNITSCHEDULEID, VERSIONID, MINRUNTIME
FROM  int_Stg.UnitScheduleOfferHourly
WHERE Hour in ({hour_binds})
AND   UnitScheduleId in ({id_binds})""".format(
  hour_binds=",".join((f":{idx}" for idx, _ in enumerate(hours, 1))),
  id_binds=",".join((f":{idx}" for idx, _ in enumerate(unitid, len(hours) + 1))),
)

res = connection.cursor().execute(query, (*hours, *unitid)).fetchall()
print(res)

If you have more than 1000 elements in either list then split the list up into multiple IN clauses.
def generate_sql_in_binds(
    name: str,
    size: int,
    start: int = 1,
    max_binds: int = 1000,
) -> str:
    in_clauses = (
        "{name} IN ({binds})".format(
            name=name,
            binds=",".join(
                (
                    f":{b+start}"
                    for b in range(i, min(i+max_binds,size))
                )
            )
        )
        for i in range(0, size, max_binds)
    )
    return "(" + (" OR ".join(in_clauses)) + ")"

query = """SELECT HOUR, UNITSCHEDULEID, VERSIONID, MINRUNTIME
FROM  int_Stg.UnitScheduleOfferHourly
WHERE {hour_binds}
AND   {id_binds}""".format(
  hour_binds=generate_sql_in_binds("hour", len(hours)),
  id_binds=generate_sql_in_binds("UnitScheduleId", len(unitid), len(hours) + 1),
)

res = connection.cursor().execute(query, (*hours, *unitid)).fetchall()
print(res)


would you show how to split if we have over 1000? I am a bit confused

Hello again, I have one more problem I am getting the error "DPY-3002: Python value of type "int64" is not supported"
I checked and apparently I have to combine your first above code  with inputHandler but I am having hard time.
which I get the error again with "name 'cursor' is not defined"

@arshamvosoughinia You should ask a new question and provide a [MRE] which includes the code you are using and the error message. It difficult to know what the problem is when we can't see the code (and asking a new question would mean more people can see it and offer solutions).

Thanks, Sounds good, I already did, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78355987/dpy-3002-python-value-of-type-int64-is-not-supported-i-need-to-combine-my-co

For a very big number of binds, you could try the last solution in the documentation and use an object type with the ... select * from table(:1) syntax.

@Avangard If you want to redact the query then replace code with other code that is syntactically valid. If you just delete bits of code and leave the answer in an invalid state then the edit will be rejected.
